# What is the prediction error while using deming regression (weighted total least squares)

Tags: regression, variance, deming-regression

[Deming Regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression) is a regression technique taking into account uncertainty in both the explanatory and dependent variable.

Although I have found some interesting references on the calculation of this property in [matlab](http://iopscience.iop.org/0957-0233/18/11/025) and in [R](http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg85070.html) I'm stuck when I try to calculate the standard prediction error. The error on the model estimate is given in both methods, but I wonder if I can use that for prediction by using the variances of their prediction.
Eg: `var(y_pred) = var(a*x+b) = E[a]^2*var(x) + E[x]^2*a+var(b)`

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the variance of y_pred in Deming Regression. I am sorry, its not clear to me.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I would like to know the prediction error when I use a new x (not one used to fit the model) trying to predict y (y_pred). The standard error of x is known.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update** I've updated the answer to reflect the discussions in the comments.

The model is given as
\begin{align*}
y&=y^{*}+\varepsilon\\\\
x&=x^{*}+\eta\\\\
y^{*}&=\alpha+x^{*}\beta
\end{align*}

So when forecasting with a new value $x$ we can forecast either $y$ or $y^{*}$. Their forecasts coincide $\hat{y}=\hat{y}^{*}=\hat{\alpha}+\hat{\beta}x$  but their error variances will be different:

$$\operatorname{Var}(\hat{y})=\operatorname{Var}(\hat{y}^{*})+\operatorname{Var}(\varepsilon)$$

To get $\operatorname{Var}(\hat{y}^{*})$ write

\begin{align*}
\hat{y}^{*}-y^{*}&=\hat{\alpha}-\alpha+\hat{\beta} (x^{*}+\eta)-\beta x^{*}\\\
&=(\hat{\alpha}-\alpha)+(\hat{\beta}-\beta) x^{*}+ \hat{\beta}\eta
\end{align*}

So

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}(\hat{y}^{*})=E(\hat{y}^{*}-y^{*})^2&=D(\hat{\alpha}-\alpha)+D(\hat{\beta}-\beta) (x^{*})^2+ E\hat{\beta}^2D\eta\\\\
& + 2\textrm{cov}(\hat{\alpha}-\alpha,\hat{\beta}-\beta)x^{*}
\end{align*}

Comment: Good answer. However, I think, if @johanvdw wants to predict for new x, the prediction error will be larger than you estimate. If I understood him correctly, var(pred_y) = var(\hat y) + var(error).

Comment: thanks, that was fast!
@suncoolsu I think the error in y should not be added. The regression coefficients already include that uncertainty. You wouldn't add it in a normal linear regression either.

Comment: @johanvdw. I think we do need to add the error in normal linear regression for prediction of a new Y (for a new X). Please see : equation 2.38 in section 2.5 of Applied Linear Statistical Models - Kutner, Nachtsheim, Neter, and Li (2005). McGrawHill

Comment: @suncoolsu and @johanvdw,  I've updated the answer to reflect your discussion. @suncoolsu is right, we need to add the error, but only if we want to forecast true $y$, if we want the forecast of $y^*$ the addition is not necessary. @johanvdw in normal linear regression error addition is necessary, since normal linear regression does not postulate the latent variable $y^{*}$

Comment: @suncoolsu, jogandw and mpiktas, please do you know a reference for the "total least squares" approach to Deming's regression ?